# Log on defaults to USA English Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

The latest update (Feb 2018) defaults to USA English keyboard. 
It is a damned nuisance. 
Can we go back to log on retaining previous preference? 
Thanks you good people. 
Bob

Answer (score 0):

To change the keyboard layout you can use :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then you can choose your layout. You might need to reboot after.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
The Terminal code you gave me provided a list of possibly 200 type faces, and I flogged through several (none said English UK) but each reboot put the keyboard back to English US.
It looks like one of the USA based Techies has set up his personal preference for all Ubuntu. 
Until recently, if you set the keyboard then it would be your choice at reboot. It is just a nuisance and a step backwards. 
I'll just have to change the keyboard every time I need £, #, @ etc. 
Ho-hum, but thanks for your reply.